# How to lock camera to Follow automatically and rotate only on command without scripts, empties

Tags: camera

I see a lot of people being suggest scripts or using as empty or track object (constraint), but the problem with Blender is it follows everything the object its a Child to (when object moves that is fine, but if the object rotates the camera rotates too).

The only thing I haven't tried is making the camera Parent, so that way the object moves with camera, but that means I have to move the camera to move the object.

Comment: Why the resistance to use empties?

Comment: To tell you the truth...at first I didn't know or realize how powerful they can be.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parenting, try a [Copy Location constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/transform/copy_location.html). Enabling the offset option allows the camera to follow the object at a set distance and it will ignore any rotation of the object it is following.

[image: Copy location constraint panel]